# how redirect output to the file in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, stdout

I tried such code to redirect standart output to the file:

```
subprocess.Popen('my command', cwd='my path', shell=True, stdout=stdout.txt, stderr=stdout.txt)
```

But got error: `NameError: name 'stdout' is not defined`

I use python version 2.5.2

Comment: Assuming the `stdout` argument could take a file name instead of a file handle (note: it can't), you would have to quote the text. As it is, Python thinks you are trying to access the `txt` attribute of an object referenced by `stdout`, not specifying a file name of "stdout.txt".

Answer (score 8):

Open the file first and use `a` to append if you want to keep a record of all output/errors or use `w` to overwrite each time:

```
with open("stdout.txt","a+") as stdout:
   subprocess.Popen('my command', cwd='my path', shell=True, stdout=stdout, stderr=stdout)
```

Using `with` will automatically close your file.

Comment: `Popen` doesn't block until `my command` completes, though, so ensure you don't leave the `with` statement before the command completes.

Comment: I try this, but got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
`

Comment: How are you using it exactly

Comment: Hi @PadraicCunningham. Thoughts on maybe adding the suggestion (or show an alternative solution) to this solution to not use `shell=True`? Understandably it's matching the OP exact code. But I came across this answer to help out someone else, and having shell != True would probably be more appropriate for a more robust solution.

Comment: @idjaw, hi, I will update with a few more options tomorrow. A s far as shell=True goes it actually depends on what you are running, for windows you actually need it.

Comment: We can also do this without having `shell=True` @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: If `stderr` writes into another file what should I do? @Padraic Cunningham

Answer (score 1):

Give a file descriptor to stdout
[See doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)